# Halide - any way to interpret Buffer as Func? [Edit: self-solved]

Tags: c++, halide

I am just wondering if there is any way in Halide to interpret a Buffer as a Func (i.e. a better identity function). Also, a lot of my code seems very redundant, so if it is possible to write it in a better style, what would that look like?

Here is an example of what I am talking about (Note: I have to use a row-major representation for other reasons):

Current:

```
#define HEIGHT dim(0).extent()
#define WIDTH dim(1).extent()

//modular addition (needs to accept Funcs as inputs
//because it will be part of a pipeline)
Halide::Func add(Halide::Func f1, Halide::Func f2, int64_t modulus) {
    Halide::Var x, y;

    Halide::Func add_temp;
    if (modulus > 1)
        add_temp(x, y) = (f1(x, y) + f2(x, y)) % Halide::Expr(modulus);
    else
        add_temp(x, y) = f1(x, y) + f2(x, y);

    return add_temp;
}

int main() {//testing the "add" function
    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in1(4, 4, "in1");
    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in2(4, 4, "in2");
    //initialize in1 and in2 to random numbers

    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> sum(4, 4, "sum");
    //side note: what does the name in the constructor even do?
    //can I just omit it? I was told to keep it.

    Halide::Func in1_id;
    Halide::Func in2_id;
    Halide::Var x, y;
    in1_id(x, y) = in1(x, y);
    in2_id(x, y) = in2(x, y);
    sum = add(in1_id, in2_id, 503).realize(4, 4);

    //print the values of sum
}
```

Ideal (version 1):

```
Halide::Func add(Halide::Func f1, Halide::Func f2, int64_t modulus) {
    //the same definition
}

int main() {
    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in1(4, 4);
    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in2(4, 4);
    //initialize in1 and in2 to random numbers

    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> sum(4, 4);
    //in1 is automatically interpreted as
    //the identity function on in1
    sum = add(in1, in2, 503).realize(4,4);

    //print the values of sum
}
```

Ideal (version 2):

```
Halide::Func add(Halide::Func f1, Halide::Func f2, int64_t modulus) {
    //the same definition
}

int main() {
    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in1(4, 4);
    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in2(4, 4);
    //initialize in1 and in2 to random numbers

    Halide::Buffer<int64_t> sum(4, 4);
    //h_id is something included in the Halide
    //library which acts as the identity on anything
    sum = add(h_id(in1), h_id(in2), 503).realize(4,4);

    //print the values of sum
}
```

It doesn't seem like a big deal at first, but the real problem is when I have to make multi-stage pipelines with multiple inputs and multiple outputs and I have to define separate identity functions for each input, which seems very redundant and unnecessary. Thank you in advance to any and all answerers!

Edit: I actually solved this myself the next day. It turns out that there was a simple solution. h_id doesn't have to be included in Halide; I could just define it myself. Here is my definition of h_id:

```
Halide::Func h_id(Halide::Buffer<int64_t> in) {
    Halide::Var x, y;
    Halide::Func ret;
    ret(x,y) = in(x,y);
    return ret;
}
```

Then I can easily call it on any buffer without having to define a new Func and create new Vars, exactly as I did in Ideal version 2.

Comment: P.S. if you see anything fishy or unnecessary in my code, please tell me! I am just starting out, after all.

Comment: A general warning to be careful with macros like `#define HEIGHT dim(0).extent()`. Because they are dumb-stupid text replacement in the preprocessor, amazingly stupid things can happen and result in inexplicable behaviour and error messages. These look fairly benign, so all you probably have to look out for is other instances of `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH`. Regardless, I'd replace them with little functions. The compiler will probably inline them so there's no runtime cost and you benefit with sane compiler messages should anything go south .

Comment: Thanks! The reason I used macros was because Halide already has functions width() and height() that use a column-major representation, and I wanted to avoid any confusion with that and I'm supposed to use a row-major representation, so oh well. Do you know if any default identity Func exists, though? Or do I have to just define a new one for each of my inputs?